# Are $L^p$ norms continuous on finite spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I believe it's a general property of a topology given by a norm that it is a continuous map from the space to $\mathbb R$. So in particular $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}:L^p\to\mathbb R$ is continuous ($1\leq p<\infty$ say). If we define these norms on a finite space then the $L^q$ norm is well-defined as long as $q\leq p$.

My question is whether this extends, so $\|\cdot\|_{L^q}:L^p\to\mathbb R$ is also continuous for $1\leq q\leq p<\infty$. My inclination is that the answer is yes because on a finite space the $L^q$ norm is "smaller" than the $L^p$ norm but I'm not sure.

Comment: By "finite space" i suppose you mean "finite-dimensional space".

Comment: No I mean finite measure space. Otherwise $q\leq p$ does not imply that you can take the $L^q$ norm of an $L^p$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that the underlying measure space $(X,\mu)$ satisfies $\mu(X)=1$. If $1\leq q\leq p<\infty$ then
$$ ||f||_q\leq ||f||_p $$
by Jensen's inequality. This implies that $L^p\subset L^q$, so the $L^q$ norm can be restricted to $L^p$.

To show that $||\cdot||_q:L^p\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, it is enough to show that $||f_n||_q\to ||f||_q$ for all $\{f_n\},f\in L^p$ with $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$.

But if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ then $||f_n-f||_p\to 0$, and since $||f_n-f||_q\leq ||f_n-f||_p$ for all $n$, this implies that $||f_n-f||_q\to 0$ as well. The triangle inequality in $L^q$ implies that
$$ |||f_n||_q-||f||_q|\leq ||f_n-f||_q $$
hence it follows that $||f_n||_q\to ||f||_q$.

Comment: That looks right, thanks! (unfortunately stackexchange says I can't upvote you yet)

Answer (score 0):

By $|•|_{Lp}$ did you mean $|•|_p$? In that case, p norm is continuous in $L_q$ space for $\forall q<\infty$.

Comment: I meant the norm $\|u\|_{L^p}^p=\int|u|^p$. Do you have a proof or reference?